# TypeScript - Array toString()

Tags: arrays, string, typescript

I need to convert this: `['CL-0191', 7, 'Surtidor 7', 2]`

to this: `('CL-0191', 7, 'Surtidor 7', 2)`

```js
//I try using toString()

let arr = ['CL-0191', 7, 'Surtidor 7', 2]
let str = arr.toString()  // CL-0191,7,Surtidor 7,2
```

result: `CL-0191,7,Surtidor 7,2`
but I want as result `('CL-0191', 7, 'Surtidor 7', 2)`

How to get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSON.stringify` almost does what you want, but you'll have to manually replace the square brackets with parentheses and the double quotes with single quotes:

```js
let str = JSON.stringify(arr).replaceAll('"', '\'').replace('[', '(').replace(']',')')
```

Comment: Thank you Mureinik. It works and does what I want.